# 'Isass' process causing TLS errors in windows server 2019 and SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, windows-server-2016

In Windows Server 2019 I installed SharePoint 2016 In Event Viewer Administration section there are may TLS errors and below is details for this error.
In Server only TLS 1.2 Enabled and other Protocols are disabled.
How to fix this error
A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013.
in Details view below is the error and here i get the process name 'Isass' why this one causing TLS errors .

Get-Process -ID 760

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable strong cryptography in .NET Framework 4.6 or higher:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Similar issue for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd626e47-9ee7-41c5-b11a-ae696e3b6b5b/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client-credential-the-internal-error-state-is-10013?forum=ws2016

Comment: I run the above reg file but i see TLS errors starting 12 Am to 3 AM and some times 9AM to 3 PM and some times when i login remotely to the server.